# How can i avoid looping through same data

Tags: c#, loops, for-loop, datatable

TB_COST.Data is my DataTable, I am looping through data and calculating some fields. I want seperate functions for each calculation but i am looping the data repeatedly. I am looking for a way to avoid repeating.

I tried to loop the data once and call functions inside but i thought it will be harder to make bug fixing later.

```
    public void CalculateCost()//this function getting called at a button onclick
    {
        try
        {
            CalculateProductPrice();
            CalculateFreight();            
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            ShowMessageBox(ex.ToString());
        }
    }

    public void CalculateProductPrice()
    {
        decimal totalTonage = Convert.ToDecimal("0");
        decimal totalPrice = Convert.ToDecimal("0");
        decimal priceCarpiTonage = Convert.ToDecimal("0");
        for(int i = 0; i < TB_COST.Data.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            decimal containerTonage = Convert.ToDecimal(TB_COST.Data.Rows[i]["CONTON"].ToString());
            totalTonage += containerTonage;
            decimal price = Convert.ToDecimal(TB_COST.Data.Rows[i]["PROPRI"].ToString());
            totalPrice += price;
            priceCarpiTonage +=  Convert.ToDecimal(containerTonage) * price; 
        }
        decimal productPrice = priceCarpiTonage/totalTonage;
        productPrice = (Math.Round(productPrice, 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero));
        //ShowMessageBox(totalPrice + " " + priceCarpiTonage + " " + productPrice);
        T_PROP.Text = productPrice.ToString();
        T_TOTN.Text = totalTonage.ToString();                     
    }
    public void CalculateFreight()
    {
        decimal totalFreight = Convert.ToDecimal("0");
        for(int i = 0; i < TB_COST.Data.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            decimal decimalFreightPrice = Convert.ToDecimal(TB_COST.Data.Rows[i]["CONPRI"].ToString());
            decimal containerTonnage = Convert.ToDecimal(TB_COST.Data.Rows[i]["CONTON"].ToString());
            decimal decimalFreightBoluContainerTonnage = decimalFreightPrice/containerTonnage;
            totalFreight += decimalFreightBoluContainerTonnage;                
        }
        //ShowMessageBox(totalFreight.ToString());
        totalFreight = (Math.Round(totalFreight, 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero));                                  
        T_FREG.Text = totalFreight.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: Why are you writing `Convert.ToDecimal("0")` and not just `0m`?

Comment: You need significant amount of code refactoring, just a hint use List and its aggregate functions i.e `Sum()` and calculate values from `TB_COST` separately and store it in list variables

Comment: Both calculations seem to be independent to each other. So firstly, you need to refactor, so the computations are on one data row, only and update a shared state object for average values. Then you can iterate only once and make both calculations per-row.

Comment: I'd also recommend to separate UI Updates and Business Logic. What if you want to calculate, without updating the UI?

Comment: one function with `totalTonage`, `totalPrice`. `priceCarpiTonage` and `totalFreight`, one loop with the logic of the two loops mixed. Seems easy, what are you having truble with?

Comment: thanks for the advices. I am updating ui because it also stores the value at database due to this systems setup. all the fields are a column in database and it stores a row everytime the form used. I think i will try something like Fildor offered. @bradbury9 thanks, I didn't want to mix calculations for later error checks and bug fixes.

Comment: The UI comments do try to tell you do not mix calculations and UI, do calculations first and after that interact with the interface. Doing maintenance of applications is a lot easier if logic and UI are not mixed.

Comment: @bradbury9 okay i understand what you mean thank you very much.

Comment: It's also better for UnitTesting. If you mix UI and Logic, how are you going to write a UnitTest for the Logic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comments and on [mr springers's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56929567/2265446) I think you just need to add some helper functions and call them inside your `for`.

Note: To make it unit testable some info of what is `TB_COST` would be needed. Then the signature would be `public CalculationsResult PerformCalculations(???? TB_COST)` and it would not have the UI interaction.

```
public void PerformCalculations()//this function getting called at a button onclick
{
    try
    {
        CalculationsResult calculations = new CalculationsResult();

        for(int i = 0; i < TB_COST.Data.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            DoMyCalculation(calculations, TB_COST.Data.Rows[i]);
            // Call other calculations
        }
        decimal productPrice = calculations.PriceCarpiTonage / calculations.TotalTonage;
        productPrice = (Math.Round(productPrice, 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero));
        T_PROP.Text = productPrice.ToString();
        T_TOTN.Text = totalTonage.ToString();   


        totalFreight = (Math.Round(totalFreight, 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero));                                  
        T_FREG.Text = totalFreight.ToString();         
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        ShowMessageBox(ex.ToString());
    }
}

private void DoMyCalculation(CalculationsResult calculations, DataRow row)
{
    calculations.TotalPrice += (decimal)row["MyColumn"];
}

public class CalculationsResult 
{
    public decimal TotalTonage { get; set; }
    public decimal TotalPrice { get; set; }
    public decimal PriceCarpiTonage { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Not bad. Just one thing: As is, `PerformCalculations` has sideeffects, so you would have to make sure, it can only be executed once at a time. You couldn't run it concurrently without messing all up.

Comment: @Fildor changed it to avoid concurrency, thanks for the feedback

Comment: I'd return the result and have the UI Updates done outside, then it's also UnitTestable.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to merge both methods to one big method:

After this, you have the problem that the method has become too large and it is not easy to maintain. So you have to refactor this method again.

You should now change this method to respect the solid principles. https://medium.com/@mirzafarrukh13/solid-design-principles-c-de157c500425

In the first step you should create a new object which represent one row of your data table. After that you should create a new method to load the data from the data table to a list of this object.

```
public class TbCost {
    public decimal Conton {get;set;}
    public decimal ProPri {get;set;}
    public decimal ConPri {get;set;}

    public decimal GetPriceCarpiTonage() {
        return Conton * ProPri;
    }

    public decimal GetFreightBoluContainerTonnage() {
        return ConPri / Conton;
    }
}

public void CalculateCost()//this function getting called at a button onclick
{
    try
    {
        decimal totalTonage = 0m;
        decimal totalPrice = 0m;
        decimal priceCarpiTonage = 0m;
        decimal totalFreight = 0m;

        IList<TbCost> tbCosts = ReadTbCosts(TB_COST.Data.Rows);

        foreach (TbCost tbCost in tbCosts)
        {
            totalTonage += tbCost.Conton;               
            totalPrice += tbCost.ProPri;
            priceCarpiTonage +=  tbCost.GetPriceCarpiTonage(); 
            totalFreight += tbCost.GetFreightBoluContainerTonnage();   
        }

        T_PROP.Text = Round(priceCarpiTonage/totalTonage);
        T_TOTN.Text = totalTonage.ToString();                                
        T_FREG.Text = Round(totalFreight);
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        ShowMessageBox(ex.ToString());
    }
}

// This method should be moved to a sperate class
private string Round(decimal decimalValue) {
    return (Math.Round(decimalValue, 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero)).ToString();
}
```

Comment: there is 2 functions but i will keep adding them and it will be like 10 functions. If i make one big function  the code will be so messed :'(

Comment: So you need helper functions that in this example would use `TbCost` and recieve a DataRow as a parameter. inside the `for` do call those helper functions.

Comment: After the refactoring it is not a problem to write unit tests

Comment: Then it would be nice to give at least a rough scribble of the desirable result of the refactoring. I am also not really sure if it actually _helps_ to make that intermediate step of that "all-in-one" function.

Comment: Unrelated: Names like `ProPri` make the code unneccessarily hard to read. Your IDE helps you with auto-complete, so no need to be not verbose, even if you are being lazy.

Comment: @Fildor it can do, as it forces you to take the entire code into account, its quite easy to dismiss one of the earlier functions you had as ok, but its existence then limits your fixing of the rest.

Comment: @cjb110 Exactly. That's why I am not determined here. It _can_ help get organized. Granted.

Comment: @Fildor I am not using visual studio, since every field is a column in database, i have to make it 6 characters because some databases can't get more than 6 characters as column name

Comment: @aliihsanmuhziroğlu I was talking about the property names in this answer. Not using VS can get somewhat troublesome. I'd reconsider that decision. What DBs are we talking about?